# Converting workbook in PDF without blank pages

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, worksheet

Hiii

I wrote a code to export sheets from one workbook to an other workbook and then convert it in pdf, but I have a lot of blank pages (maybe because of hidden formula or I don't know.

If you have any idea for what to add to my code in order to have a decent file it would be very appreciated.

```
 Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\User\Documents\Tests Salome\dailypdf.xlsx"

 Dim wbto2 As Workbook: Set wbto2 = Workbooks("dailypdf.xlsx")
 wb.Activate
For Each sht In Sheets
   If sht.Name <> "USD" And sht.Name <> "Balance" Then
      Else
     sht.Copy Before:=wbto2.Sheets(wbto2.Sheets.Count)
     Rows("140:351").EntireRow.Delete '(I tried to delete the hidden rows)

   End If
 Debug.Print sht.Name
Next

wbto2.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


            FileName = Create_PDF(Source:=wbto2, _
                                      FixedFilePathName:=iFile, _
                                      OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                                      OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)
```

The code functions but the result does not satisfy me because of the blank pages..

Answer (score 0):

you can try any option below

1.Delete all unwanted rows before saving as PDF.

2.Set Print area

3.try to save excel range as PDF directly

```
    'Enter Worksheet name, range Address, PDF file path and name
    Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("A1:D50").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Temp\PDF_name.pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: the problem is that this code is part of a big procedure where the sheets data change so i can not really give a range area and I also need to export the 2sheets together in one pdf file

Comment: I also need to export the 2sheets together in one pdf file

Comment: nothing i just need to add the two sheets "eur" and "balance"

Comment: Use the "Sheets("Sheet Name").UsedRange" method with this solution to make it dynamic.